# Livecharts save to png x axis min and max too small

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, livecharts

I am using this [example](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/master/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/Chart%20to%20Image/ChartToImageSample.xaml.cs), except the chart is displayed inside a window. I remove it from the grid then set it as the child of the viewbox.

The problem is that x axis max and min is too small that the points are not visible. The points are simple values from 1 to 500. See the x axis only goes for 0.045 to -0.05. y axis seems to be correct as there are 500 points.
[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MouseDoubleClick="Window_MouseDoubleClick">
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="Chart" DisableAnimations="True" Zoom="Xy" Pan="Xy">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding Data}"></lvc:LineSeries>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LiveCharts;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ChartValues<double> Data { get; set; } = new ChartValues<double>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            Data = new ChartValues<double>(Enumerable.Range(0, 500).Select(x => (double)x));
        }

        private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid.Children.Remove(Chart);
            Chart.Width = 1920;
            Chart.Height = 1080;
            var viewbox = new Viewbox();
            viewbox.Child = Chart;
            viewbox.Measure(Chart.RenderSize);
            viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), Chart.RenderSize));
            Chart.Update(true, true); //force chart redraw
            viewbox.UpdateLayout();

            SaveToPng(Chart, "chart.png");
            this.Content = viewbox;
        }

        private void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
        {
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            EncodeVisual(visual, fileName, encoder);
        }

        private static void EncodeVisual(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
        {
            var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bitmap.Render(visual);
            var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            using (var stream = File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "out.png"))) encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question? Do you mean that your values are between 0.045 and 0.05? Or the font is too small?

Comment: @Yvonnila output png y axis maximum and minimum is 0.045 and -0.05. Actual y values are between 0 and 500.

Comment: Well in your question you say "y axis seems to be *correct* as there are 500 points."

Comment: I could assume that for some reason, your chart doesn't have any Values. Can you see your Chart in your Window? Is it like this only when you save it as png?

Comment: @Yvonnila I mixed the x and y axis. Yes I can see the chart in the window. Problem is only when saving as png.

Comment: After removing the chart from the window, the binding can now longer be resolved as the DataContext is set on the window.